# Symfony 2.1 with PHPPDF

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I am trying to include an image (a jpg file) into a pdf being created using the phppdf bundle of Symfony 2.1.3.

I am able to create pdf's but cannot get them to include images.

I am using, inside the twig template:

```
img src="{{ pdf_image('gimage.jpg') }}"
```

I have tried putting the jpg in a number of different places and tried a number of different paths e.g. `img src="{{ pdf_image('XX/XX/XX/gimage.jpg') }}"` but nothing works. I have also tried the path to the image without `pdf_image`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [psliwa PdfBundle](https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle)?

If so it says to use..

```
<img src="{{ pdf_image('SymfonyWebConfiguratorBundle:blue-arrow.png') }}" />
```

Which I think would be linking to..

```
path/to/SymfonyWebConfiguratorBundle/Resources/blue-arrow.png
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. That is the bundle I am using. I think it is now pointing at the image file but I get the following error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 105 bytes) in /var/www/vendor/psliwa/php-pdf/lib/PHPPdf/Core/Node/Node.php on line 1298

Comment: I have tried it with a tiny image and also increased the memory to 256MB.

Comment: Then I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for trying. In case anyone else has the same problem, I have now got it working for very small images (20K) by increasing the memory limit further. It appears there is something wrong with the design of the bundle. Also the path to the images is not as in Qoop's answer but is ..bundlename/Resources/public/images/blue-arrow.png